# trouble reading data from binary file into struct array

Tags: arrays, struct

I have a binary file with some data I inputted using an array of struct.

However, when I try to read back my values and display them, only the first one prints followed by garbage values.

Where did I go wrong?

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct eagleEmployees{
    char userName[16];
    char psswd[16];

};

int main()
{
    int i;
    struct eagleEmployees data[3];

    FILE* fptr;

    fptr = fopen("eEmployees.bin", "wb");

    for(i=0; i<3; i++){

        printf("\nEnter client name %d: ", i+1);
        scanf(" %s", data[i].userName);

        printf("\nEnter client password %d: ", i+1);
        scanf(" %s", data[i].psswd);
   }

   i++;

   fwrite(data, sizeof(struct eagleEmployees), 3, fptr);

   fclose(fptr);

   // I close the file above and reopen for reading below.

   FILE *f;
   f = fopen("eEmployees.bin", "rb");

   for(i=0; i<3; i++){

   fread(data,1,sizeof(struct eagleEmployees), f);

   printf("\n %s \t %s",data[i].userName, data[i].psswd);

   }

   fclose(f);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Running as is is ok. However, if i only run the read portion at the bottom i get one value and the rest is garbage.